# How to make SVN repositories browsable through http protocol

Tags: apache, http, svn, windows-xp, httpd.conf

I've just installed **SVN**. I would like to know the steps for making SVN repository browsable through **http** in my LAN, without the need for the network administrator to open up another custom **port**. This is an [exemple](http://svn.mozilla.org/projects/mozilla.com/trunk/) of how it should look like.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it :)

1. I had to move the two following modules :

   1. mod_authz_svn.so
   2. mod_dav_svn.so

located in the `DirectoryOfInstallationOfSVN\bin` to `DirectoryOfInstallationOfApache\Modules` and copied the DLLs files from the first directory to `DirectoryOfInstallationOfApache\bin`.

1. After that I had to configure the httpd.conf file located at `DirectoryOfInstallationOfApache\conf`  by adding following :

   ```
    <Location /svn>
          DAV svn
         SVNPath "path to your SVN repository goes here" (without the double quotes )
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Write here whatever you like"
         AuthUserFile "DirectoryOfInstallationOfApache\bin\passwd" 
         Require valid-user

     </Location>
   ```
2. One may find some PORT related issues, you can change the port at which the Apache is Listening by modifying the #`Listen` command in the httpd.conf file.
3. Finally, in order to be able to add new users, don't forget to copy the `passwd` file located in `DirectoryOfInstallaionOfSVN\repository\conf` to `DierctoryOfInstallationOfApache\bin`. You will be able then to add new users to SVN via cmd using :

   ```
    htpasswd -m passwd "new username goes here" (without the double quotes).
   ```

You will be asked to provide a password twice for the new user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a module to apache. On RPM/Cent OS it is mod_dav_svn
Thereafter you need to configure apache VHOST to use it.

This [HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion) should help you set it up on Cent OS/Red hat

This [one](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-subversion-svn-with-apache2-and-dav/) for Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks bro :) any idea for windows xp ?

Comment: If you are using apache on windows, then the process should be similar to that in Linux. All you need to do is relate and modify the steps accordingly. Modules mostly will be the same.
Seems like you already managed to do that.. nice work  :)

Comment: thanks @anup :) don't forget to upvote my own answer if you think the steps are correct.

Comment: not enough in the kitty on stackoverflow. Should have posted in serverfault.   :)
Nevertheless, you have contributed a solution to the ones looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have "SVN repository browsable through http" you must to install Apache with SVN-related modules and configure it properly.

More easy way for Windows-case will be

- Install [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)
- In server settings use for "SVN Parent Directory" parent directory of your *existing repository*

Answer (score 1):

Install SVN via apache so you use http rather than svn protocol, then its best to install one of the many viewer programs that allow you to browse the repository with a nice UI. For example, [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/)

Comment: Thanks @gbjbaaanb :) But how can I install SVN using http ? concerning client I will use subversive plugin Eclipse :)

Comment: I thought you already had installed it? If you're really new to it all, try UberSVN which packages a lot of things you need into a single installer that configures everything for you.